# How to create and store managed objects containing the data using Swift 3.0 in Xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm getting an error 'use of unresolved identifier 'Contacts' '( it's the name i have given as Entity name in my 'fileName.xcdatamodeld' ).

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext         
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()         
    }
    @IBAction func SaveContact(_ sender: Any) {
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Contacts",in: managedObjectContext)

        let contact = Contacts(entity: entityDescription!,insertInto: managedObjectContext) // Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'Contacts'
    }
    @IBAction func Findcontact(_ sender: Any) {
    }
   }
```

Comment: Is your data model configured to generate the classes?

Comment: may be not. can you tell me how to configure that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you configure the Core Data codegen in Xcode 8:
[image: Example entity details]

You have 3 options:

- Manual/none
- Class Definition
- Category/Extension

I think they are pretty self-explanatory. Anyway what you probably want here is Class Definition.